# Advanced SQL Query get value from ID referenced result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the following schematic

```
*City Table*

| ID | Name | CountryCode | District | Population
| 1  | York | GBP         | Yorkshire| 843844
| 2  | London ......

*Country Table*

| Code | Name | Continent | Region | Population | GNP | LocalName | Capital
| ABW  | Aruba| North Am  | Carrib | 843743     | x   | something | 834 (id)
```

I need to get a list of all the cities in a country where the city population is greater than the population of the capital of that city.

My current SQL query

```
SELECT City.ID, City.Name, Country.Name, City.District,               Country.Region, Country.Continent
FROM Country INNER JOIN City ON Country.Code = City.CountryCode 
WHERE (Country.Capital != City.ID) AND
(City.Population > (Country.Capital))
ORDER BY Continent;
```

It's just missing that final filter (WHERE?) that states that the population must be greater than that of the capital city for the same country of that city.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join the `City` table twice: One for the actual city that you are comparing, and one for the capital:

```
SELECT City.ID, City.Name, Country.Name, City.District,           
    Country.Region, Country.Continent
FROM Country
INNER JOIN City ON Country.Code = City.CountryCode 
INNER JOIN City AS Capitals ON Country.Capital = Capitals.ID
WHERE (City.Population > Capitals.Population)
ORDER BY Continent;
```